# Filtering a column for exactly one word and three words in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to scan one column and return only rows that have one or three words. I have tried using the below query snip but it didn't return anything. Any suggestion?

```
SELECT
      Column_1
      Column_2
FROM Table
WHERE 
      Column_1 LIKE '% %' OR Column_1 LIKE '% % %'
```

Data Examples:

`Column_1` would contain the following:

`Check;ACH;Wire`
or
`Check;Wire`
or
`ACH`

Comment: Just a simple string example: `Car`

Comment: It may be time for a crash course in [How to use LIKE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm)

Comment: I updated the question with data values for reference. I'm not even sure if `LIKE` is the right approach, but can't find a clear path forward while looking online.

Comment: You needed `or` although that wasn't going to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your words are separated by `;` and you can trust that , one way is by counting them :

```
select * 
from tablename 
where 
  (datalength(Column_1) - datalength(replace(Column_1,';',''))) / datalength(';') in (1,2)
```

Comment: @lptr then pass nvarchar parameters to datalength as well, see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c7ff154480a0ada92a5539bf353fa1f)*